# how to get list of words whose parts of speech never change

Tags: nlp, naming-conventions, naming

I am working some NLP project . I need to find all the words in English whose parts of speech never change (ie: always have a single parts of speech in any sentence). Can anyone suggest how to find them and is there any specific name to these kind of words.

Comment: I am not convinced this is possible. English has dynamics like nominalization (using verbs as nouns) and using adjectives as verbs, etc. So even if it has never been used before with a given POS, it _could_ be. So, I would say that this task depends on the corpora you choose.

Comment: And IF you do frame this as a function of a corpus, that suggests an approach - just POS tag every word in a corpus, and have a dict like {"token": [list of pos tags assigned to token]}, then you just look for all keys of length 1